# Partition and sorting of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

```
>> arr = [10, 11, 4, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 13]
>> np.partition(np.array(arr), -3)

array([ 9,  5,  4,  3,  2,  7, 10, 11, 13])

>> np.sort(np.partition(np.array(arr), -3)[-4:])

array([ 7, 10, 11, 13])

>> np.argpartition(np.array(arr), -3)

array([6, 4, 2, 3, 7, 5, 0, 1, 8], dtype=int64)

>> np.sort(np.argpartition(np.array(arr), -3)[-4:])

array([0, 1, 5, 8], dtype=int64)
```

what is going on in this code? Actually, I have gone through the documentation but could not understand this numerically.

Comment: Have you tested the code piece by piece, starting with the inner most expression (which is evaluated first).  Try to understand individual steps first.  Better yet, add that analysis to your question, displaying the results at each step.

Comment: @hpaulj it is edited. Thankyou

Comment: It would be better to use: np.sort(np.partition(np.array(arr), -3)[-3:]), since the `partition` doesn't promise what the `-4` term will be.  Note what  `arr[0,1,5,8]` is, [10,11,7,13]`, same numbers as the earlier sort/partition, but in a different order.  I don't think this last sort does anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad practice that you named a plain, pythonic **list** as *arr*.
For now this is just a **list** and **arrays** will be created further on.

To better comprehend what is going on, it is advisable to divide the code
into steps and save each partial result under separate variables.
This is how I have rewritten your code.

So let's start from:

```
lst = [10, 11, 4, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 13]
```

The second step is to create an **array** from this list:

```
arr1 = np.array(lst)
```

I decided to name this (and following arrays) as "arr" with consecutive numbers.

The third step is to **partition** *arr1*, placing the "threshold" element at
the third position from the end:

```
arr2 = np.partition(arr1, -3)
```

The result is:

```
array([ 9,  5,  4,  3,  2,  7, 10, 11, 13])
```

Details:

- The "threshold" element (*10*) is located at the third position from the end.
- All preceding elements are smaller than the threshold.
- All following elements are greater or equal to the threshold.
- Nothing can be said about the order of elements both before and after the
  "threshold" element.

Then you want to get last 4 elements of *arr2*:

```
arr3 = arr2[-4:]
```

No surprise, the result is:

```
array([ 7, 10, 11, 13])
```

The next step is to sort them:

```
arr4 = np.sort(arr3)
```

This time nothing has changed, the content of *arr4* is just the same as *arr3*.

So far you finished your experiments with *partition*, the second part is to
experiment with *argpartition*:

```
arr5 = np.argpartition(arr1, -3)
```

The result is:

```
array([6, 4, 2, 3, 7, 5, 0, 1, 8], dtype=int64)
```

It is an array of **indices** to *arr1*.

Details:

- The third element from the end (*0*) is the index of the "threshold"
  element in *arr1* (its value is *10*).
- All previous elements are indices of smaller elements (in *arr1*).
- All following elements are indices of greater or equal elements (in *arr1*).

Then you get last 4 elements of *arr5*:

```
arr6 = arr5[-4:]
```

getting:

```
array([5, 0, 1, 8], dtype=int64)
```

And the last step is to sort them:

```
arr7 = np.sort(arr6)
```

getting (no surprise):

```
array([0, 1, 5, 8], dtype=int64)
```

That's all.

Comment: So now you can accept my answer.